# Spinner with sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one spinner, one button and a ListView.

I want to choose item from spinner and after clicking button the match of spinner and database content must be show in the ListView. The database values are of string data type.

Please anybody can guide me how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Spinner sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final ArrayList<String> options=new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor cursor=dbHelper.getOptions();//method to get all options to be displayed in spinner,coming from your database

        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
            {
                 options.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("field_name")));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,options);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                  Cursor c=db_helper.getRelatedItems(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()); //get related data from database according to the item selected in spinner
                  if(c.getCount()>0)
                  {         
                       CustomAdapter ca=new CustomAdapter(context,R.layout.listitem_layout,cursor,new String[]{"field 1","field 2"},new int[]{R.id.textview1,R.id.textview2});
                       //here you would have to pass your custom layout file containing textviews or other component to display your data using CustomAdapter.class which you had prepared 
                       listview.setAdapter(ca);
                       ca.notifyDataSetChanged();

                       listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
                              @Override
                              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                                //catch onClick on items of listview here
                              }
                       });
                 }  
           }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

For spinner,first create an adapter like:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.months, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

// Here R.array.months are string array created at string.xml file and then open ur database:

```
if(mydb_expenditure!=null)
{
    mydb_expenditure.close();
}

mydb_expenditure=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Database_name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
if(mydb_expenditure!=null)
{
    Cursor cursor = mydb_expenditure.rawQuery("select column name from "+TableName , null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int column=cursor.getColumnIndex("column name");
    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        do
        {
            column=cursor.getInt(column);
            adapter12.add(column);
        }while(.moveToNext());
    }
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter12);
}
```

This will add ur ur database column value into the spinner

Comment: user932478 ,If u think that this answer is useful for you then click on the tick left of this answer to make it visible to all the users and also to increase ur answers accept ratio to get relevant answers...

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this steps assuming spinner is populated with string array:

i)    In  `setOnItemSelectedListener` event get position of selected position by

`int pos=urspinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` and get string by

```
 strsel=arrstr[pos];
```

ii) on button click listener use `strsel` to populate listadapter by querying database

DONE!!!!